# How do I connect modules in python?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Starting to do some more advanced processes in flask and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to import my error handling file. Code snipets from init and errors. What's wrong?

I cant get the errors module to load. I've tried doing from errors import *, I get an import error, tried moving it out of the factory still get errors. Tried from errors import *, tried import errors. All fail to some degree. Seems to me I'm missing something simple as a comma or something.

here's some code

first file - init

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

def create_app():
    # Instantiate App
    app = Flask(__name__)

    with app.app_context():
        # Import Blueprints
        from .foodtracker.routes import foodtracker
        from .fitness.routes import fitness
        from .bio.routes import bio
        from .home.routes import home

        # Import models, and error handler
        from . import errors

        # Register Blue Prints
        app.register_blueprint(foodtracker)
        app.register_blueprint(fitness)
        app.register_blueprint(bio)
        app.register_blueprint(home)

        return app
```

and errors.py

```
from flask import render_template
from . import app

@app.errorhandler(404)
def pagenotfound(error):
    return render_template('/errors/404.html'), 404
```

directory structure

```
/fitlife
   /fitlife
      /bio
      /home
      /fitness
      /foodtracker
   __init__.py
   errors.py
   models.py
```

Comment: you have circular import.. its not good.

Comment: whats the proper way to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You have circular imports. Meaning, the `app` file tries to import the `errors` file and the `errors` file tries to import the `app` file.
The correct way to handle this would be to 'dumb down' the `errors.py` file, meaning making it only contain the errors themselves without using the decorator to register them. Then, the `errors.py` file will not need to import `app`.
The registration can be done using [`app.register_error_handler`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/#registering) from the higher-level file, instead.

Comment: i took this concept from this tutorial. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vii-error-handling

not correct?

Comment: It's not that it's not correct. There is more than one way to register an error handler. But if you definitely **have** to import `errors.py` in the `app` file (which maybe you don't?), then you can't have `errors.py` also import `app`. From an architectural perspective, you need to think who uses who, or in other words - _who depends on who?_

Comment: my thought process was to keep my init file as "clean" as possible with only application level calls - factories, config, blueprints.. I initially started adding all my errors handlers in the init file, but it started to grow. Figured it would have it's own file to handle it all.

Comment: while also being a catch all for any error. Hence me linking it to "app"

Comment: I understand, though why are you importing `errors.py` in the `init` file at all? I don't see you using it anyway.

Comment: based on what I understood from the tutorial I mentioned, The idea was to define all the errors in the error file by means of the decorator, register the errors file in the init file so that when the errors do show up, the functions in errors.py would handle them. The way your saying, I still have to register the error handler in the init file individually. Seems to me to be doing things twice. I got it working by using the app.register_error_handler, but it seems like twice the work?

Comment: so currently I'm doing from .errors import * and then in the factory registering the error handler as app.register_error_handler(404, pagenotfound). pagenotfound is defined the errors.py file. I guess my point was to avoid manually registering it one by one, and just importing the whole file as a catch all. Is it possible without a circular import?

Comment: Why is it twice the work? Instead of writing a decorator, you write a `register_error_handler` line. I'm not sure what the best practice for Flask is, which is worth checking, but in the grand scheme of things you should think what you really want the structure to be.

Comment: I see what your saying, it's really moving the @app decorator and changing to a register_error_handler line. I guess in my head I was trying to eliminate those lines from the init file.  I'm still fairly new, and still figuring out best practices.

Comment: I guess to avoid the circular import and the extra move, might as well have @app decorator in the init file anyway and skip the error file altogether?

Comment: That's possible, but I think having an `errors` file can be pretty useful. Again I'm not sure what the best practice is for Flask, so it's worth checking, but making things modular makes sense.

Comment: Maybe you don't even have to import the `errors` file in `__init__`, but just register using the decorator. Else, this won't make sense, at all.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your time and input. I'll look into best practices. If you have any recommendations for good reads I'll take it!